# Adding SBT task to Play project's full build configuration

Tags: scala, sbt

How do I add a task to a Play (SBT) project that uses a full build configuration, say `Build.scala`, so that it is actually visible and can be used?

Apparently what I did is not enough. When I run `play tasks` the new task is not listed and I cannot run it.

**Build.scala** looks as follows:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val hello = TaskKey[Unit]("hello", "Prints 'Hello World'")

  val helloTask = hello := {
    println("Hello World")
  }  

  val appName         = "test"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"        
  val appDependencies = Seq(
    jdbc
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(       
    resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"      
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the `helloTask` as a setting within `settings` method as follows:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
  helloTask
)
```

See [Full Configuration Example](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Examples/Full-Configuration-Example.html) for SBT **0.12.4** since you use the older approach to define tasks with `TaskKey` and the double assign (`helloTask = hello :=`). You may find the reference to [Scalaz's full build configuration](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/project/ScalazBuild.scala) very useful (at the very bottom of the page).

Comment: nice, now i can run it from the console! one more thing: i still cannot see it when i run "tasks" or "tasks -v"?